# Cannot Resolve Symbol GetAccessControl in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to write a function in **.net core 3.1 Class Library**, to check **file** user rights.

Unfortunately, .net core 3.1 does not recognize GetAccessControl.

I have attached NUGET

- System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0
- Microsoft.Windows.Compatability 7.0.0

Nothing works so far.

```
 public static bool CheckFileAccess(string path, string domainUser)
        {
            var result = false;
            try
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var acl = File.GetAccessControl(file.Name);
                    // do something with the acl

                    var rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

                    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
                    {
                        if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(domainUser, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("User does not have access to the file.");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: .NET Core 3 reached End Of Life last year. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6. There's no `File.GetAccessControl` in .NET Core anyway, and can't be added by adding the 7-year old System.IO.FileSystem package

Comment: There's a [GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemaclextensions.getaccesscontrol?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesystemaclextensions-getaccesscontrol(system-io-fileinfo)) extension method defined for `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo` and `FileStream` objects.